# Video created with FFmpeg has a strange contrast level while playing in some video players

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using these parameters to encode multiple PNGs into a MP4 file using `FFmpeg`:

```
-vsync 2 -safe 0 -f concat -i ".\concat.txt" -c:v libx264 
-pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "pad=width=2044:height=1152:x=0:y=0:color=black" -y ".\Test.mp4"
```

But it's creating a video in which some players are not capable of displaying the correct contrast level. What's happening? I'm probably doing something wrong.

Windows Media Player and MP-HC are not displaying with the correct contrast level, but the Movies and TV is able to.

[image]

Here is the MediaInfo of the video:

```
General
Complete name                  : .\Color.mp4
Format                         : MPEG-4
Format profile                 : Base Media
Codec ID                       : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                      : 550 KiB
Duration                       : 6 s 560 ms
Overall bit rate               : 687 kb/s
Writing application            : Lavf58.29.100

Video
ID                             : 1
Format                         : AVC
Format/Info                    : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                 : High@L5
Format settings, CABAC         : Yes
Format settings, RefFrames     : 4 frames
Codec ID                       : avc1
Codec ID/Info                  : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                       : 6 s 560 ms
Bit rate                       : 684 kb/s
Width                          : 2 044 pixels
Height                         : 1 152 pixels
Display aspect ratio           : 16:9
Frame rate mode                : Variable
Frame rate                     : 15.244 FPS
Minimum frame rate             : 12.500 FPS
Maximum frame rate             : 25.000 FPS
Color space                    : YUV
Chroma subsampling             : 4:2:0
Bit depth                      : 8 bits
Scan type                      : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)             : 0.019
Stream size                    : 548 KiB (100%)
Writing library                : x264 core 158 r2984 3759fcb
Encoding settings              : cabac=1 / ref=3 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=18 / lookahead_threads=3 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=23.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
```

And here is the MediaInfo of the PNG:

```
General
Format                         : PNG
Format/Info                    : Portable Network Graphic
File size                      : 1.35 MiB

Image
Format                         : PNG
Format/Info                    : Portable Network Graphic
Format_Compression             : LZ77
Width                          : 2 043 pixels
Height                         : 1 152 pixels
Bit depth                      : 24 bits
Compression mode               : Lossless
Stream size                    : 1.35 MiB (100%)
```

I'm using this version of `FFmpeg` (nightly build, but I also tested with 4.2.1):

```
ffmpeg version git-2019-10-25-b78227e Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20191010
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 
       --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass 
       --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame 
       --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg 
       --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr 
       --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack 
       --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg 
       --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis 
       --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid 
       --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va 
       --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt 
       --enable-amf
      libavutil      56. 35.100 / 56. 35.100
      libavcodec     58. 59.100 / 58. 59.100
      libavformat    58. 33.100 / 58. 33.100
      libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
      libavfilter     7. 59.100 /  7. 59.100
      libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
      libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
      libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
```

### EDIT

So, after disabling the Contrast Enhancement in **Intel UHD Graphics Control Panel**, the video plays normally in **Media Player - Home Cinema** and in **Windows Media Player**:

[image: After fixing]

Now, why was the **Movies and TV** app not affected by this option? Was it because it was running with the discrete GPU instead? Or maybe it was not using the standard video codec?

Comment: I nowhere see what color range your input files and output video is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you, by any chance, using an Intel Graphics card? If so, try opening  Intel Graphics Properties and try setting **Input Range** and **Standard Color Correction** to *Application settings*

Comment: HAHA! I did disable the Contrast Enhancer in the **Intel UHD Graphics Control Panel** and now the video played by **MP-HC** is displaying correctly.
Thanks. Now, why was the other player not affected by this option?